# pip package loses package data after reboot

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have installed my python project with the help of setuptools and defined some static txt,conf and html files. But my problem is that, after rebooting my debian System, the script doesn't finds the static files anymore. I defined them in the MANIFEST.in as follows:

```
include data/*.conf
include data/*.html
include data/*.txt
```

this is my setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="dnwtools",
    version = "0.0.4",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
          'jinja2',
          'pymysql'
    ],
    entry_points = {
        "console_scripts": [
            "dnwtools = dnwtools.main:main",
        ]
    },
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

Thank you for your help in advance !

Comment: Python/pip/setuptools certainly have nothing with the problem. `tmpfs` could be cleaned, e.g. Or some `@reboot` cron job.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem on my on: id just had to ad the `__file__` variable to